# tomcat doesn't start on server startup

Tags: 14.04, tomcat

Following [this tutorial](http://nixmash.com/java/starting-tomcat-on-bootup-in-ubuntu/), I am trying to make tomcat start on server startup.

I created this file:

> ```
> export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_05
> export CATALINA_HOME=/ubuntuland/utils/apache-tomcat-8.0.8
>
> case $1 in
> start)
>     sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
>     ;;
> stop)
>     sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh
>     ;;
> restart)
>     sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh
>     sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
>     ;;
> esac
> exit 0
> ```

with the correct Java and Catalina env. variables, and put it under `/etc/init.d/tomcat`

I ran the following commands:

> ```
> sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/tomcat
> sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/tomcat /etc/rc1.d/K99tomcat
> sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/tomcat /etc/rc2.d/S99tomcat
> ```

However, after doing:

```
sudo reboot
```

Tomcat is still not running.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a headless server? I had that issue with a headless server; I chose a lazy solution of just adding the code to `/etc/rc.local`:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_05
export CATALINA_HOME=/ubuntuland/utils/apache-tomcat-8.0.8
    
sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
    
exit 0
```

add this code to `/etc/rc.local`

and make a script with this code in `/etc/init.d/shutdown.sh`

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_05
export CATALINA_HOME=/ubuntuland/utils/apache-tomcat-8.0.8
sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh
```

save it then

```
sudo chmod a+x /etc/init.d/shutdown.sh
```

and make a symbolic link of that to `/etc/rc0.d/`

```
sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/shutdown.sh /etc/rc0.d/K04shutdown.sh
```

and it will run at shutdown.

I don't know java so i just left the export statements there, doesn't matter.
Now run this command which will run the script at reboot as well, assuming you have the scripts `startup.sh` and `shutdown.sh` in your home directory and you defined the environment variable correctly:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/shutdown.sh /etc/rc6.d/K04shutdown.sh
```

Good luck

Answer (score 2):

This line should do the trick. Tested on Ubuntu 18.04

```
sudo systemctl enable tomcat
```

Source: [digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 0):

One way to start the tomcat on the startup is to run it using cron using the @reboot attribute:

open up a terminal and type :

```
sudo crontab -e
```

at the end of the file enter the command:

```
@reboot /`PATH_TO_WHERE_TOMCAT_INSTALLED`/bin/startup.sh
```

save the file and exit.

The above command will run the command once everytime computer boots up.